Vmware Fusion ubuntu18.04 dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks after install open-vm-tools-desktop
When I wanted to implement copy and paste for Mac and Ubuntu 18.04, I installed open-vm-tools-desktop. However, after restarting, I found that I couldn't enter the system and displayed dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks
How to fix it？Ubuntu 18.04 has sufficient storage space, and the sda1 partition has 1.2GB

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.
